# Como empujar los otros layouts al hacer scroll en Listview

Tags: android, listview

Buenas, como ven en la imagen que pongo a continuación(dicha imagen no corresponde con mi app, esta sacada de google porque me sirve como ejemplo), tiene una `listview`, y lo que quiero es al hacer scroll hacia arriba con el dedo, el layout de arriba que contiene el logo y el nombre(en este caso HARU), se esconda hacia arriba, así la la `listview` pasaría a ocupar casi toda la pantalla a excepción de la botonera inferior.

He probado a poner un scrollview al layout que envuelve toda la pantalla menos la botonera, pero entonces el scroll de la listview no me funciona.

PD: creo que lo de la imagen no es un listview, pero imaginense que lo es, en mi aso el ancho del listview, es match parent.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al listview que está dentro del scrollview agregale lo siguiente:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!